# Trying to save file from Flash to PHP using $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]

Tags: php, flash, image, save, global

Let me start by saying PHP isn't my forte, I'm usually reluctant to try working with it because of problems exactly like this. The code works fine on my local machine under MAMP and on my server, but doesn't on the clients server :'(

So what am I trying to do, well - save an image from Flash onto the server, simple right?!

I'm using the method described on this site here: http://designreviver.com/tutorials/actionscript-3-jpeg-encoder-revealed-saving-images-from-flash/ but have made a small alteration so that instead of echoing the jpg causing the browser to download it locally, I do an fwrite and an fclose to save it to the server.

Here is my PHP:

I've dona a phpinfo() on my clients server and it's running 5.2.2 my host is running 5.2.11 I don't know if much can have changed in those 9 minor revisions?

I've also read another question on here which suggests making suer always_populate_raw_post_data is set to ON, but it's set to OFF on all of the server environments I've been testing in. I'm doing some XML saving using file_get_contents('php://input') which I've tried but failed to get working with images.

Any help would be gratefully received, I'm happy to post the AS3 as well but it's EXACTLY the same as example I've linked above and works locally. As far as I can tell the problem lies with the PHP.

Cheers.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does the file not get uploaded, or its name not transmitted?

Comment: Just a silly question: Have you checked the file permissions?

Comment: Thanks for the responses 

@Pekka I can see the php file being called, but the files don't get updated/overwritten

@Eineki yes, I have 775 set on all the folders/files I'm trying to write

Comment: @joly then you are posting the wrong part of your code, aren't you? There is no file upload / overwriting taking place in the PHP script you are posting.

Comment: @pekka does the fopen / fwrite / fclose not handle the file writing?!

Comment: @joly where does `$jpg` come from?

Comment: @pekka, sorry the snippet got truncated when I pasted it into my original post - hopefully this will work:

if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"]))
{
$jpg = $GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"];

Comment: @joly does that variable actually contain something? What does a `strlen()` on it return?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you're using the HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA? If Flash is sending the file via the POST method, it'd be by far easier to use the `$_FILES` array. There'd be no need to fopen/fwrite, as the file's already been stuck into a temp dir by PHP. All you have to do is use `[move_uploaded_file()][1]` to put it wherever you want on the server.

Comment: thanks Marc, the reason I'm using it is because that's what was in the example I found & as it was working locally I had no reason to doubt it's ability
using $_FILES can I pass a parameter to move_uploaded_file to set the name over the file to move?

Comment: That's exactly how it works. `move_uploaded_file(source, destination)`, in your case it'd be `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['nameofuploadfield']['tmp_name'], '/some/directory/on/the/server/name_of_file.html')`

Comment: I'm pretty curtain I've worked out what the problem is, the clients host is a crappy shared affair and the "max_input_time" in the php.ini is set to -1